# Compact Sets and Diagonals

Tags: general-topology

Prove a topological space $X$ is compact if and only if the diagonal of $X \times X$ is compact.

(I already know that if $X$ is $T2$ then the diagonal is closed)

Hence, if $X$ is compact then $X \times X$ is compact. The diagonal is a closed subspace of a compact space implies it is compact.

Now it is the other direction. Assume the diagonal is compact. Any hints will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious bijection between $X$ and the diagonal of $X\times X$ is easily seen to be a homeomorphism.